# wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<div class= 'slide <%= 'showing' if i == 0 %>' data-id<%= user.id %>
    <li>
      <div class = "image-carousel" style='background-image: url('<%= url_for user.images.first, width: '200px' %>)>

      </div>
        <%= user.first_name %>
```

using this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5gAaZq-sPs

I've been stuck for the past 4 hours I need a pick me up

Comment: `url('<%= url_for user.images.first, width: '200px' %>)` has two arguments. It is almost certainly a typo on your part. I don't think the function accepts dimensions

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple errors with the `style` attribute.

Firstly, you're using a single quote after `=` and then again to set the values within the url function. You're also not closing the `style` values.

Secondly, the url function does not accept a width. You probably need to specify the `background-size` attribute to modify the size of the image.

Try something like this

```
<div class = "image-carousel" style="background-image: url('<%= url_for user.images.first %>')">
```

Comment: D'oh! I edited the answer to add the missing quote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`url_for` just takes one argument, this is what the error says:
you passed two arguments to a method that only accepts one or no arguments.

And I think you might want to use the `asset_url` method instead: you can use it like so:

```
<div class = "image-carousel" 
     style='background-image: url('<%= asset_url user.images.first %>')">
```

Comment: In the video he deletes the `width` part from the helper at minute 32:02 or so